# Create .GIF from a video with one loop has problem in firefox

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I have a video and I want to create the animated `GIF` from the part of the video using `adobe photoshop CS6`. When I select the frames and generate the `GIF` by setting the option of `loop forever` it works fine. But when I generate the `GIF` by setting the option of `loop once`, the generated animated `GIF` doesn't work in `firefox`. The animations work fine in `chrome` but in `firefox` I only see a static image.

Any solution?

Comment: btw, what software generate the GIF?

Comment: There's an old bug report about that at mozilla's bugzilla.org: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805392.  Animations are looping one less iteration in Firefox than in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, it seems a bug of firefox. I resolved making the last frame of animation during 10 seconds and the animation "forever"; in this way firefox plays for 10 seconds the last frame and it seems played once.
Not beautiful but worked for me! See it at www.namastudio.it